# React Invalid hook call with wordpress guttenberg

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, wordpress-gutenberg

I am working with WordPress Gutenberg blocks and am trying to build a timeline using timeline js. The edit part of the code is working great, but the save part is not working and is throwing

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this
> problem.

The code for the save page is

```
import { useEffect } from "@wordpress/element";
import { useBlockProps } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

export default function save({ attributes }) {
  const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
  const { files } = attributes;

  useEffect(() => {
    new TL.Timeline("timeline-save-embed", files);
  }, [files]);

  return (
    <>
      <div {...blockProps}>
        <div className="timeline-container">
          <div
            id="timeline-save-embed"
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "600px" }}
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This error is a result of putting `{...blockProps}` inside the JSX because what it will do is calling a hook as a prop to a `<div>` component which is not allowed.

Comment: The error is popping up at useEffect and not at blockProps, I tried removing blockprops but the error did not change

Comment: React components have to start with a captial letter - `Save` instead of `save`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue is that WordPress Gutenberg accepts pure functions on the frontend/ Save part of the code and does not accept side effects in the frontend, so the only workaround currently is to, use dynamic blocks written in PHP

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).